# Square zone recognition on the photograph of Rubik's Cube -- Algorithm Suggestion?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, vision

I have built a robot that solves Rubik's cube. It is working fine but I am hoping someone could suggest a good way to recognize square zones on the photograph of a cube side. Here is a typical photo (left) and the result of the zone detection (right). The robot takes 2 pictures per face, with the top and bottom grippers retracted (as shown here) and another with the left and right grippers retracted. So 7 square zones need to be detected per photo:

[image]

Currently I apply Canny transformation, detect all isolated contours, figure out which contours are squarish, and select 7 that approximately form the letter "H" (vertical or horizontal).

[image]

I realize that this is a pretty blunt approach -- a zone does not always translate to a clean disconnected contour. My algorithm works in about 90% of cases, and I want something like 99% or even 99.9% as this seems like an easy task. Can anyone please suggest a good approach for this type of computer vision problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two separate images for each face of the square, you can instead hold the cube just using the left and right grippers but have both of them grab the top and bottom of the cube so there are no obstructions in the image. You could then do it where you look for a square rather than an H letter or you could crop the image down to remove the unneeded parts of the background to potentially get better results.